# How can I declare a two dimensional array with the <array> header?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I know how to declare a two dimensional arrays like this:

```
int arr[5][5];
```

But I want to do it in a different way, just like we declare a one dimensional array like this:

```
array<int, 5> arr;
```

How can I declare a two dimensional array using the second method of declaration of arrays?

Comment: You could do what the (good) answers show *or* you could just declare a one dimensional array of the proper size but *use* it as a two dimensional array. That's always an option.

Comment: The reference documentation should explain everything well enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an array of arrays, like so:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5> arr;
```

Unfortunately there is no "short" syntax, but you can create one:

```
template <class T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
using two_dim_array = std::array<std::array<T, cols>, rows>;

two_dim_array<int, 5, 5> arr;
```

Comment: With the directly nested `std::array` the order of sizes , `array<array<int, n_columns>, n_rows>` is opposite of the indices when that beast is used, `a[i_row][i_column]`. With your `two_dim_array` the order of declaration is the same as the order of indexing, which is fine, but not clear. I have no good solution for the clarity though, but I like a compromise notation that also has the order right, but adds some declaration clarity in exchange for not fixing the verbosity: `array_of<n_rows, array_of<n_columns, int>>`.

Answer (score 4):

```
array<array<int, 5>, 5> arr;
```

Comment: I'd upvote this (as I did atb's now deleted answer) if not for the verbose and misleading text. Remove the text and you get my +1. ;-)

Comment: @cheers - Ok Alf, short and sweet? Also voted to undelete atb's answer.

Comment: Yep. :) +1 ]]]]]]

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the array of an array

```
std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5> arr;
```

And if you are not sure of size of array, better declare a 2-D vector

```
vector<vector<data_type>> 2dMatrix;
```

And if you know the size of 2-D matrix then, it can be declared this way.

```
vector<vector<data_type>> 2dMatrix(row,vector<data_type>(column));
```